# how to get the last committed offset for a consumer in Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have an Spring Boot Microservice app that reads from a Kafka Topic . the app read from the topic and stopped midway before it consumes all of the data from the topic.The app has been stopped for 2 months and now when I start the app back its showing a load of 0 which is wrong as it hasn't read all of the data? Is there a way to get the last committed offset for a consumer ?

Comment: Kafka has a default topic retention of only 1 week, so this seems accurate.

Comment: The broker maintain the offsets in private topics, and there are some configurations for how long offsets are stored before they're reset to 0.  See offsets.retention.minutes here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <brokers> --group <id> --describe` to find the committed offsets

If the current and latest offets match, or the lag is zero, then there are no messages to read